# Solve the linear system by Gaussian elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

$\begin{cases}-2b+3c=1 \\ 3a+6b-3c=-2 \\ 6a+6b+3c=5\end{cases}$

I got an inconsistent linear system with the third row being 0 0 0 6.

May someone please verify if I am right? I looked it over.

Comment: It is difficult to say whether your calculations are correct, since you didn't show us your calculations. But you are correct in saying that the system has not solutions. It suffices to notice that if you add $3\times$the first equation, $2\times$ the second equation and $-1\times$ the third equation, you get $0=-6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations are correct, since you end up with the last line of the matrix being 0 0 0 6 the last equation in the reduced matrix has no solution so the whole system has no solution